# Having trouble switching sprites

Tags: c#, xna

Ok I have a player class which contains movement code etc.
My problem is when the key "2" is pressed I want the player sprite (which is by default unarmed) to switch to a guy with a gun.

I got this working until I tried to add a third gun into the game, at which point I can only see the two guns by holding the "2" and "3" keys the whole time.

I want it to toggle and I think my use of boolean may be the cause, but here's the code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Audio;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.GamerServices;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Input;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Media;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Net;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Storage;

namespace Teir_Tactical_2A 
{
    public class Player
    {
        public Texture2D playerunarmed;
        public Texture2D playerM1911;
        public Texture2D playerM4;
        public KeyboardState keyState;
        public KeyboardState oldKeyboardState;
        public Vector2 playerPosition;
        public SpriteBatch spriteBatch;
        public float Angle { get; set; }
        public float AngularVelocity { get; set; }
        public Vector2 playerVelocity = Vector2.One;
        public bool unarmed;
        public bool M1911;
        public bool M4;
        public bool IsToggled = false;
        float angle;

        public Player(ContentManager content, Vector2 location)
        {
            this.playerunarmed = content.Load<Texture2D>("PLAYER");
            this.playerM1911 = content.Load<Texture2D>("PLAYERM1911");
            this.playerM4 = content.Load<Texture2D>("PLAYERM4");
            playerPosition = location;
            unarmed = true;
            M4 = true;
            M1911 = true;           
        }

        public void Update()
        {
            MouseState curMouse = Mouse.GetState();

            if (M1911 == true)
            {
                armed();
            }

            if (unarmed == true)
            {
                armed();
            }

            if (M4 == true)
            {
                armed();
            }

            Vector2 mouseLoc = new Vector2(curMouse.X, curMouse.Y);
            Vector2 direction = mouseLoc - playerPosition;
            angle = (float)(Math.Atan2(direction.Y, direction.X));
            keyState = Keyboard.GetState();         

            if (keyState.IsKeyDown(Keys.D1))
            {
                unarmed = true;
                M4 = false;
                M1911 = false;              
            }

            if (keyState.IsKeyDown(Keys.D2))
            {
                M1911 = true;
                M4 = false;
                unarmed = false;         
            }

            if (keyState.IsKeyDown(Keys.D3))
            {
                M4 = true;
                unarmed = false;
                M1911 = false;
            }                     

            if (keyState.IsKeyDown(Keys.D))
                playerPosition.X += playerVelocity.X + 1;
            if (keyState.IsKeyDown(Keys.A))
                playerPosition.X -= playerVelocity.X + 1;
            if (keyState.IsKeyDown(Keys.W))
                playerPosition.Y -= playerVelocity.Y + 1;
            if (keyState.IsKeyDown(Keys.S))
                playerPosition.Y += playerVelocity.Y + 1;
        }

        public void Draw(SpriteBatch spriteBatch)
        {
            spriteBatch.Begin();
            {
                Rectangle sourceRectangle = new Rectangle(0, 0, playerunarmed.Width, playerunarmed.Height);
                Vector2 origin = new Vector2(playerunarmed.Width / 2, playerunarmed.Height / 2);

                if (unarmed == true)
                {
                    spriteBatch.Draw(playerunarmed, new Rectangle((int)playerPosition.X, (int)playerPosition.Y, playerunarmed.Width, playerunarmed.Height), null, Color.White, angle + 90, new Vector2(62, 70), SpriteEffects.None, 0f);
                }

                if (M1911 == true)
                {
                    spriteBatch.Draw(playerM1911, new Rectangle((int)playerPosition.X, (int)playerPosition.Y, playerunarmed.Width, playerunarmed.Height), null, Color.White, angle + 90, new Vector2(62, 70), SpriteEffects.None, 0f);
                }

                if (M4 == true)
                {
                    spriteBatch.Draw(playerM4, new Rectangle((int)playerPosition.X, (int)playerPosition.Y, playerunarmed.Width, playerunarmed.Height), null, Color.White, angle + 90, new Vector2(62, 70), SpriteEffects.None, 0f);
                }
            }
            spriteBatch.End();
        }

        public void armed()
        {
            M1911 = false;
            M4 = false;
            unarmed = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Now heres where I think the issue is, its in here

```
if (keyState.IsKeyDown(Keys.D1))
{
    unarmed = true;
    M4 = false;
    M1911 = false;

}

if (keyState.IsKeyDown(Keys.D2))
{
    M1911 = true;
    M4 = false;
    unarmed = false;        
}

if (keyState.IsKeyDown(Keys.D3))
{
    M4 = true;
    unarmed = false;
    M1911 = false;
}
```

Somehow, I've got to make it so that the keys toggle, so that when I press "3" it makes sure that the M1911 and the unarmed variables are set to false, and the M4 value is set to true.

Am I going about this the right way?

I've also tried the IsKeyUp && IsKeyDown method, where you link the current state to the old state, but that only causes the gun to flicker onto the screen breifly before it dissapears so If theres a way to fix that, then that would be great

EDIT: so is there a way to edit the armed method so that when a key is pressed the weapon state is altered?

2ND EDIT: I figured it out, I gave each weapon state its own armed(); variable and then added the true/ false settings in the bottom armed(); variable here:

```
    public void armedM1911()
    {
        M1911 = true;
        M4 = false;
        player = false;

    }
    public void armedM4()
    {
        M4 = true;
        M1911 = false;
        player = false;
    }
    public void unarmed()
    {
        M1911 = false;
        M4 = false;
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

you're calling the `armed()` method at the beginning of each update loop regardless of your weapon state

```
if (M1911 == true)
{
    armed();
}

if (unarmed == true)
{
    armed();
}
if (M4 == true)
{
    armed();
}
```

which apparently calls

```
public void armed()
{
    M1911 = false;
    M4 = false;
    unarmed = true;
}
```

which sets both your weapons to false, and `unarmed` to true

So even thought you might toggle your state at the end of the loop, it will always reset again the next loop when you let go of the key.